# Questions regarding Pentaho Report designer

Tags: mysql, pentaho, pentaho-report-designer

1. I have a `datetime`-type column in MySQL. Now, in my report I want to use only the date part for

   a. grouping

   b. comparison

I tried looking for a solution on the net, however I couldn't find it.

2. How to use `distinct` in the SQL query in report designer. If I design the following query

   ```
   SELECT COUNT (DISTINCT user_id) FROM mytable
   ```

it converts the same to

```
SELECT DISTINCT COUNT (user_id) FROM mytable
```

Please help.

Answer (score 0):

I never ran into such behavior, but, anyway, I think a quick (but not the best) workaround would be to use the following query:

```
select 
      count(0) 
from 
      (select distinct user_id from mytable) t
```

Answer (score -1):

Doesn't work in version 3.9.1
It keeps changing it to give priority to DISTINCT
I will give it a go to use the summarisation functions of Report Designer itself.

Cheers

AC